# Existance of array in list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to check the existence of an array in a list of arrays. My problem can be boiled down to the example below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> c = [a,b]
>>> c
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
>>> a in c
True
>>> np.array([1,2,3]) in c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> d = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> d in c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I check the existence of an array in a list of arrays? This works as I'd expect when I use regular lists:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = [a,b]
>>> [1,2,3] in c
True
>>> [4,5,6] in c
True
>>> [1,2] in c
False
>>> d = [1,2,3]
>>> d in c
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

c = np.array([a,b]) # < ---- this line!

print repr(c)
print a in c

print np.array([1,2,3]) in c 

print [1,2,3] in c # Success!!!
print np.array([1,2,3]).tolist() in c# also success!!!
```

Comment: In python 3.5, numpy 1.10.4, "ndarray1 in ndarray2" appears to return true if the first element in ndarray1 occurs in ndarray2, while the other elements of ndarray1 are completely ignored

Comment: That is, this does not answer the original question, and infact I do not think using the 'in' keyword on ndarrays was intended to have well defined behavior by the numpy devs.

Answer (score 2):

Joran's solution is good because it lets you use the intuitive `in` function you probably want to use.

However, if for some reason you cannot change the type of `c` to be an `np.array` then this function will solve your problem with the original data types of `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
>>> def new_in(seq, elem):
>>>    return elem.tolist() in map(lambda e: e.tolist(), seq)

>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> c = [a,b]

>>> new_in(c,a)
>>> True
```

Comment: +1 ... but may want to ensure you use a generator version of map with `itertools.imap` ... otherwise you will convert the whole original sequence to normal lists in python2 ... but the reality is 99.999% of the time that wont really be an issue

Comment: Agreed. If the `seq` was long or infinite (iterator) then `itertools.imap` instead of simply `map` makes more sense. Anyways, better to just wrap OP's example sequence `c` in an `np.array` as you did. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be used to solve this problem in a numpythonic manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.contains(c, a)
```

Note that it does not involve any casts to python types, and uses no python loops, so it can be expected to be much more efficient when using arrays of substantial size. The 'a' array can also be multidimensional, so that you can test for the presence of multiple values in a single vectorized statement.

Be ware that the currently accepted answer does not produce well defined results.